# Tryint to select td text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```js
$(document).ready(Principal);
function Principal(){
 var howMuch = $('[class^="toShow"]').length;
 for(var i=0; i<howMuch; i++){
  console.log($('[class^="toShow"]')[i]);
 }
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr><td class="toShow">text1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="toShow">text2</td></tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And as you can see, I'm displaying that entire td by console, but I just need the text inside that two tds, on this case, "text1" and "text2".

I've tryed with `...)[i].text, .content, .val(), .value(), .content`.. but it displays undefined..

Is there any way to get that text?

Comment: wow, so simple, thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing an attribute selector for an exact class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`$.fn.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```js
$(document).ready(Principal);
function Principal(){
    $('[class^="toShow"]').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
        console.log(this.textContent);
    });
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr><td class="toShow">text1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="toShow">text2</td></tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```